# Separate category item angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How to list items in AngularJS and separate them by category, something like this:

```
<h3>Products</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="item in products">
  <div>
      {{item.category}}
  </div>
       <p>
         {{item.name}}
       </p>
        <p>
         {{item.price}}
       </p>
  </div>
```

$scope:

```
$scope.products = [
        {
           name:"product1",
           price:"450",
           category:"cat1"
        },
         {
           name:"product2",
           price:"450",
           category:"cat2"
        },
         {
           name:"product3",
           price:"450",
           category:"cat1"
        }
    ];
```

I want it to look something like this:

cat1

--->product1

--->product3

cat2

--->product2
...

Please help!

Comment: Do you want to categorize odd and even products separately ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [fiddle])(http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2846/)

I did some formatting to message the data in desired format.

```
$scope.productCategories = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.productCategories[products[i].category] == undefined)
      $scope.productCategories[products[i].category] = [];
    $scope.productCategories[products[i].category].push({
      name: products[i].name,
      price: products[i].price
    });
```

}

Html Formatting is off, but I hope this gives you an idea

Answer (score 0):

you can use groupBy filter in ng-repeat. you should add groupBy filter dependency in your app.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",['angular.filter']);

app.controller("ctrl" , function($scope){
  
  $scope.products = [ { name:"product1", price:"450", category:"cat1" }, { name:"product2", price:"450", category:"cat2" }, { name:"product3", price:"450", category:"cat1" } ];
  
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" class="panel-group" id="accordion">

       <h3>Products</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in products | groupBy: 'category'">
  <div>
      {{key}}
  </div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in value">
       <p>
         {{item.name}}
       </p>
        <p>
         {{item.price}}
       </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please if my answer is useful for you accept it. thanks.